# Object to assoc array with json (decode / encode)

Tags: php, arrays, json, object

I have an object which I want to be convert to an `assoc array`.
I use `json` for this, but I got as result:

`Array([0] => Array([id]=>12 [label]=>home)`

But I need
`Array([id]=>12 [label]=>home)`, otherwise `$page["id"]` won't work.

How can I fix this problem?

Code:

```
$page = json_decode(json_encode($page),true);
$id = $page["id"];
```

Comment: Why not `$page = (array)$page;`

Comment: You get 2 level array and you want just the inner?.. $page = $page[0]; ?

Comment: Because I got this Daan: Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [label] => home

Comment: Show us what `$page` contains before it gets changed

Comment: @Svetlio  $page = $page[0]; works, but I wonder why I got an array in an array. No other way?

Comment: Because `$page` is already an array in the 1st place - an array of stdClass objects

Comment: @Fluinc Ah I see, the fault is somewhere in the object... Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [id] => 12 [label] => home

Comment: so `$page = (array)$page[0];` will give you what you need without serialization

Comment: In the question you have wrote Array([0] => Array > This means array in array.. No std class objects.

Comment: @Svetlio im guessing thats the output of the serialization hack, originally `$page` would be an array of objects

Comment: @Steve nope.. if you make json_decode($json, TRUE) this will move and the inner objects into arrays.

Comment: Very strange, for one page it works with $page = $page[0], for another it doesn't and I have to use $page = json_decode(json_encode($page),true); without $page=$page[0]...

Comment: @Nico var_dump your $page on the different pages to see what is the difference.. 
If $page is empty $page=$page[0]; wont work .. you can add and if(isset($page[0])) before setting it..

Comment: Ah ofcourse, by one there are more results, so I have to for each loop it. In that case json decode encode is easier to use!

Comment: @Svetlio thas what im saying, the output in the question (showing a multidimentional array) is the result of the json hack, the array of objects in the comments is the original input.

Comment: @Nico why do you even need to cast to an array. why not just use object notation, eg `$id = $page->id;`? Also, if your code sometimes returns a single object, and other times an array of objects, then that should be considered a bug - have it always return an array, with only a single element if required

Comment: @Steve Doesn't work for one page... Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in ..
Warning: Attempt to assign property of non-object in ......
That's the page where I have to use $page = (array)$page[0]

Comment: @Steve Oh wait, I can fix it which this line... $page = $page[0]; And then everything in object notation

Comment: Well thats because in that case, `$page` is an array of objects. As i said, you really should fix your code to always return an array of objects, even if there is only one. However the following line will always work: `$id = is_array($page)? $page[0]->id : $page->id;`

Comment: @Steve Thank you very much, learnt a lot!